# Makefile generates and output .o files to a subfolder

Tags: c++, makefile

I have some difficulty generating .o to 'src/build' using Makefile. Below is my structure.

```
Project
├── include
│   └── Solution.hpp
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └──
    ├── build
    │   └── 
    ├── Makefile
    ├── Solution.cpp
    └── main.cpp
```

What I want to do is generate main.o and Solution.o under src/build folder and then generate executable file 'test' under src/bin. After running my Makefile, I got main.o in src/build but Solution.o in src. I am not sure why? The variables OBJDIR and BINDIR should set where the targets are, correct? If I remove $(OBJECTS), everything works fine. Any help for why I cannot output all .o files to src/build?

```
ROOTDIR       ?= ..

BINDIR        := bin
OBJDIR        := build
INCLUDEDIR    := $(ROOTDIR)/src $(ROOTDIR)/include 

CXX           := g++
CCFLAGS       := -c -g -O2 -Wall -std=c++17
LINKFLAGS     := 

SOURCES       := main.cpp Solution.cpp
OBJECTS       := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE    := test

OBJSUFFIX     := .o

all : $(BINDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE)

makedirs :
    @if test ! -d $(BINDIR); then mkdir $(BINDIR); fi
    @if test ! -d $(OBJDIR); then mkdir $(OBJDIR); fi

## Link ##
$(BINDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LINKFLAGS) -o $@ $^

## Compile ##
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.cpp makedirs
    $(CXX) $(CCFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean :
    rm -rf $(BINDIR) $(OBJDIR) *.o
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
$(BINDIR)/$(EXECUTABLE) : $(OBJDIR)/$(OBJECTS)
```

I see people do this *all the time* on SO and I'm not sure why it's so seductive but it clearly cannot work when you think about it.

You have this:

```
SOURCES       := main.cpp Solution.cpp
OBJECTS       := $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

So `OBJECTS` is `main.o Solution.o` and `OBJDIR` is `build`.

So what does `$(OBJDIR)/$(OBJECTS)` expand to?  Here's a hint: make doesn't somehow discover that `$(OBJECTS)` has multiple words and infer that you want to apply the prefix to each word.  It simply expands the variables as written.  So the results of this expansion are `build/main.o Solution.o`.  And that's why you get the behavior you do.

You want to write this:

```
OBJECTS       := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(SOURCES))
```

or this:

```
OBJECTS       := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
```

to ensure that the directory is applied to each word individually, not just pasted to the front of the first word.

Comment: Another thing that we see all the time here on SO is people making things harder than they need to be by forcing build results into special, non-default directories, as in this case.  I have never understood this.  The objective of keeping the source directory clean is better served by out-of-source building, and I have yet to run across another motivation that doesn't boil down to an arbitrary decision to do things the hard way.

Comment: I think people don't like out-of-source building because you have to start your build from a different directory than you use to manage your source, and there's no way to know where that is except by remembering it ("did I put my build in ../obj or ../build or /tmp/obj or ...")  It can also be a little tricky to write the makefile properly if you have generated files, you want to write `install` rules, etc.  I don't think it's anything against the concept of out-of-source builds per se.

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion works. addprefix is a good option to add prefix to EACH word. Thanks.